# How do I handle a InvalidMediaType exception being thrown from DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRender in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

The [DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/error/DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer.java) is throwing an InvalidMediaType exception when the request accept header is invalid. I need to send an appropriate response in json when this happens, however the content negotiation is falling back to sending out the stack trace even though an appropriate error message had been set on the response.

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up adding a Filter earlier in the chain that attempts to parse the media type and if the invalid media type exception is thrown it responds with Http Status code 415.